# Haskell Task Instance

Tags: haskell

I saw this exercise in a book and I am trying to do it but can't get any further.

What I'm trying to do is implement, for the data type, a function

```
area_t :: p -> Double
```

that returns the area of a general triangle.

The data type Triangle defines the function "area_t".

My current code:

```
data Triangle = MTriangle {
                        tP1 :: Point,
                        tP2 :: Point,
                        tP3 :: Point}
                      

class Polygon p where
  area_t :: p -> Float



instance Polygon Point where

instance Polygon Triangle where
    area_t
```

**Error** :

```
      Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’
                  with actual type ‘Point -> Point -> Float -> Point’
    • The equation(s) for ‘area_t’ have three arguments,
      but its type ‘Point -> Float’ has only one
```

Answer (score 1):

The area of a point is 0, so the instance for `Polygon Point` (if you consider points to be polygons at all), should be:

```
instance Polygon Point where
    area_t _ = 0
```

Then the code you wrote for the area of a triangle seems alright, but there's two problems:

1. You are pattern matching on three separate points instead of a triangle
2. You are producing a point instead of a plain float

A working instance might look like this:

```
instance Polygon Triangle where
    area_t (MTriangle (MPoint x1 y1) (MPoint x2 y2) (MPoint x3 y3))
      = ((x2-x1)*(y3-y1) - (x3-x1)*(y2-y1))/2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `area_t` function return just a plain (positive) Float number, rather than a MPoint object ?